# DataGridView Date format change while print in C#

Tags: c#, date, gridview, printing

I have a data gird view that display date in Arabic language, however when i print this grid view the date came out in English, how to fix this ?

Comment: Show us how you format your date column please.

Comment: `dg.Columns.Add(utils.DG_CreateColumn(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells, DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, "a_start", "تاريخ البداية", true, true));`

Comment: This is the code that add the date column to the grid view, its not the application i created, im doing edits, i went through everywhere, but can't seem to find where the date format has been set, however the date display fine on the screen, but when i use the print, it change and come out in English not the language its been displaying into.

Comment: I changed the default cell style  as @mateuz suggested but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Use [Column.DefaultCellStyle.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format.aspx) property or set it  [in designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/95y5fz2x.aspx?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28VS.CELLSTYLEDIALOG%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK&k=VERSION=V4.0%22%29&rd=true)